# Why did not find then when insert there is duplicate key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework Code First, and below logic is: if the message is found by the keys, then update, if not found, then insert, but sometimes, the log shows that did not find, will insert, then duplicate key exception.

The error log is:

> Not found related pumper info record in latestpumper status table, will insert into. Verbose General

and then

Error General

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.LatestPumperStatus'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LatestPumperStatus'. The duplicate key value is (EXO_ONPREM, , DM-C3, EWS_Error_Impact_By_Org_V1).

```
            LatestPumperStatus pumperStatus = dbContext.LatestPumperStatusTable.Where(info =>
                string.Compare(info.Datacenter, streamInfo.DataCenter ?? string.Empty, true) == 0
                && string.Compare(info.Datamart, streamInfo.Datamart ?? string.Empty, true) == 0
                && string.Compare(info.Scope, streamInfo.Scope ?? string.Empty, true) == 0
                && string.Compare(info.DatamartTable, streamInfo.DatamartTable ?? string.Empty, true) == 0)
                .FirstOrDefault<LatestPumperStatus>();
        PumperLogger.LogVerbose("PumperProcessor: Start to try to find related pumper info record in latestpumper status table with this PumperStatusDataStreamInfo:", SerializeToXml<PumperStatusDataStreamInfo>(streamInfo));
        if (null == pumperStatus)
        {
            PumperLogger.LogVerbose("PumperProcessor: Not found related pumper info record in latestpumper status table, will insert into.", SerializeToXml<PumperStatusDataStreamInfo>(streamInfo));
            pumperStatus = new LatestPumperStatus();
            pumperStatus.SetValue(streamInfo, enqueuedTime, true);
            dbContext.LatestPumperStatusTable.Add(pumperStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            PumperLogger.LogVerbose("PumperProcessor: Found related pumper info record:", string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", pumperStatus.Scope, pumperStatus.Datamart, pumperStatus.Datacenter, pumperStatus.DatamartTable));
            pumperStatus.SetValue(streamInfo, enqueuedTime, false);
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The definition of the LatestPumperStatus'

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Pumper Scope 
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(20)]
    public string Scope
    {
        get
        {
            return this.scopeValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                this.scopeValue = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                this.scopeValue = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, 20));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pumper Datacenter
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), StringLength(20)]
    public string Datacenter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataCenterValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (null == value)
            {
                this.dataCenterValue = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                this.dataCenterValue = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, 20));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pumper Datamart
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column(Order = 3), StringLength(32)]
    public string Datamart
    {
        get
        {
            return this.datamartValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (null == value)
            {
                this.datamartValue = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                this.datamartValue = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, 32));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pumper Target Table
    /// </summary>
    [Key, Column(Order = 4), StringLength(128)]
    public string DatamartTable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.datamartTableValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (null == value)
            {
                this.datamartTableValue = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                this.datamartTableValue = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, 128));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If two machines run your code at the same time, they will both see that no row exists, then they will both try to add the same row.

To solve this, you need to catch that exception so that the second machine can stop.